# Does tapping Swiftfoot Boots remove Hexproof from the creature it's equipped to?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

So if my buddy has [Emrakul, the Promised End](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bEmrakul%2c%20the%20Promised%20End%5d), and it's equipped with [Swiftfoot Boots](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bSwiftfoot%20Boots%5d), and I use [Pacification Array](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bPacification%20Array%5d) to "tap target artifact..." can I tap the boots, thus eliminating the hexproof for that turn?

Comment: Why do you think tapping the Boots would remove Hexproof?

Comment: It's basically game over if he gets that equipped and I don't have a destroy target artifact. I was thinking that maybe tapping it would disable its abilities.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Tapping an artifact, or any other permanent, does not change its abilities, or whether those abilities have an effect, unless the ability says so. Tapped vs untapped is simply part of the status of a permanent [[CR 110.6](http://mtg.gamepedia.com/Permanents)].

Historically, artifact abilities did in fact "turn off" when that artifact was tapped. Many of those cards have since been reworded to explicitly only work when the permanent is untapped. Examples include [Winter Orb](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bWinter%20Orb%5d), [Static Orb](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bStatic%20Orb%5d) and [Howling Mine](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bHowling%20Mine%5d).

Comment: In addition, tapping an Equipment does not prevent its Equip-ability from being played, unless tapping it is an explicit part of the costs for that ability (though I am unaware of any Equipment having to tap to equip).